# Checkboxes rendered on separate line (CSS, vue)

Tags: css, vue.js

I have a Vue component Checkbox and browsers render them on separate line. I want to have all checkboxes side by side until they wrap to new line and so on.

[image]

A generated code use block DIV but even if I changed it to SPAN there was no effect. There is too much CSS classes written by previous developer. I tried to switched them off but either it did nothing or it destroyed the rendering at all. I have extracted minimum reproducible sample at https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-currying-woeh6

The code is very large and I would rather post a small portion but people downvote the questions with incomplete sources. So I am sorry I paste it here. I recommend to open the codesandbox as it is easier to read.

Checkbox.vue

```
<template>
  <ValidationProvider
    class="relative"
    tag="div"
    v-model="innerValue"
    :vid="vid"
    :rules="rules"
    :name="name || label"
    v-slot="{ errors, required }"

  >
    <input
      class="atoms__checkbox-input"
      :class="{ 'border-gray-700': !errors[0], 'border-red-600': errors[0] }"
      :id="identifier"
      v-model="innerValue"
      :value="identifier"
      type="checkbox"
      ref="input"
    >
    <label :for="identifier" class="atoms__checkbox-label">
      <span>{{label}}</span>
    </label>
  </ValidationProvider>
</template>

<script>
import { ValidationProvider } from 'vee-validate';

export default {
  props: {
    vid: {
      type: String,
      default: undefined,
    },
    identifier: {
      type: String,
      default: undefined,
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
    label: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
    rules: {
      type: [Object, String],
      default: '',
    },
    value: {
      type: null,
      default: '',
    },
    checked: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  components: {
    ValidationProvider,
  },
  data: () => ({
    innerValue: null,
  }),
  watch: {
    innerValue(value) {
      this.$emit('input', value);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
  .relative{
    clear: both;
  }

  .atoms__checkbox-label {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 34px;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .atoms__checkbox-label:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: 4px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 15px;
    border: 2px solid #9e9e9e;
  }

  .atoms__checkbox-label span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }

  .atoms__checkbox-label:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 5px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffd302;
    border-left: 2px solid #ffd302;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(0);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(0);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(0);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(0);
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    left: 8px;
  }

  .atoms__checkbox-input[type="checkbox"] {
    opacity: 0.00000001;
    position: absolute;
  }

  .atoms__checkbox-input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label::before {
    color: #ffd302;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  }

  .atoms__checkbox-input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label::after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1);
  }
</style>
```

Component.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="sign-up-wrapper">
    <div class="sign-up__heading">
      <h2>Form</h2>
    </div>
    <ValidationObserver ref="form">
      <form>
        <div class="sign-up-form__label">
          <label for="vehicle">Vehicles</label>
        </div>
        <div class="sign-up-form__input">
          <Checkbox v-model="bike" label="bike" name="vehicle" identifier="bike"/>
          <Checkbox v-model="car" label="car" name="vehicle" identifier="car"/>
          <Checkbox v-model="bus" label="bus" name="vehicle" identifier="bus"/>
          <Checkbox v-model="van" label="van" name="vehicle" identifier="van"/>
          <Checkbox v-model="truck" label="truck" name="vehicle" identifier="truck"/>
          <Checkbox v-model="tramway" label="tramway" name="vehicle" identifier="tramway"/>
        </div>
      </form>
    </ValidationObserver>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ValidationObserver } from "vee-validate";
import Checkbox from "@/components/Checkbox.vue";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  components: {
    ValidationObserver,
    Checkbox
  },
  data: () => ({
    bike: null,
    car: null,
    bus: null,
    van: null,
    truck: null,
    tramway: null
  })
};
</script>

<style>
.sign-up-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  padding: 1em 0;
}

@media all and (min-width: 850px) {
  .sign-up {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    max-width: 80%;
  }
}

.atoms__checkbox {
  width: 9em;
  float: left;
}
.atoms__radio {
  width: 9em;
  float: left;
}

#sign-up-form-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

#sign-up-form-success {
  color: green;
}

.sign-up-form__label {
  font-size: 25px;
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.sign-up-form__errors-heading {
  color: rgb(209, 49, 49);
}

.sign-up-form__year {
  width: 4em;
}

.sign-up-form__input {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}

select {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.sign-up-form__button {
  width: 100%;
}

@media all and (min-width: 850px) {
  .sign-up-form__button {
    width: 30%;
  }

  #sign-up-form-wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 0.3fr 1fr;
  }

  .sign-up-form__input {
    /*width: 70%;*/
  }
}
</style>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <header class="app__header-wrapper">
      <div class="app__header">
        <div class="app__header-logo-image">
        </div>
        <div class="app__header-logo-text">
          <h1>BUD</h1>
          <h2>Slogan</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <main>
    <HelloWorld/>
    </main>
    <footer class="app__footer">
      <ul class="app__footer-link-list">
        <li class="app__footer-link-list-item"><router-link to="/help">Help</router-link></li>
      </ul>
    </footer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
};
</script>

<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #000;
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.app__header-wrapper {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #ffd302;
}

.app__header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  padding: 1em 0;
}

.app__header-logo-text {
  grid-column: 2 / span 2;
  padding-top: 30px;
  line-height: 23px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.app__header-sign-in {
  grid-column: auto / span 3;
  font-size: 16px;

  a {
    color: #ffd302;

    &.router-link-exact-active {
      color: #a08500;
    }
  }

  a:hover {
    color: #ffe45b;
  }
}

.app__footer {
  background: #000;
  color: #ffd302;
  padding: 5px 0 15px 0;
}

.app__footer-link-list {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  padding: 15px 15px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.app__footer-link-list-item {
  display: inline-block;
}

.app__footer-link-list-item a {
  color: #ffe45b;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.app__footer-link-list-item a:visited {
  color: #ffd302;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.app__footer-link-list-item a:hover {
  color: #ffd302;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.app__footer-link-list-item:after {
  content: "\b7\a0";
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

.app__footer-link-list-item:last-child:after {
  content: "";
}

@media all and (min-width: 850px) {
  .app__header-wrapper {
    height: 200px;
  }

  .app__header-sign-in {
    grid-column: 3 / 3;
    padding-top: 80px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  .app__header-logo-text {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    padding-top: 50px;
    line-height: 20px;
  }

  .app__header-logo-image {
    grid-column: 1 / 1;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: You might want to read up about CSS flexbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found a combination that fixes the trouble

I had to remove these CSS attributes:

```
.sign-up-form__input {
  overflow: auto;

.atoms__checkbox-label {
  display: block;

.atoms__checkbox-label span {
  position: absolute;

.atoms__checkbox-label:after {
  display: block;
```